# Laravel image intervention resize and put in storage

Tags: laravel, intervention

When a user uploads a picture I want to store it in multiple formats.
My code for handling the image:

```
$img = Image::make($file)->encode('png');
if($img->width()>3000){
    $img->resize(3000, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
}
if($img->height()>3000){
    $img->resize(null, 3000, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
}
$uid = Str::uuid();
$fileName = Str::slug($item->name . $uid).'.png';

$high =  clone $img;
Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($bathroom->id, $fileName, "high"), $high);


$med =  clone  $img;
$med->fit(1000,1000);

Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($bathroom->id, $fileName, "med"), $med);

$thumb = clone   $img;
$thumb->fit(700,700);
Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($bathroom->id, $fileName, "thumb"), $thumb);
```

As you see I tried a few variations.

I also tried:

```
    $thumb = clone   $img;
    $thumb->resize(400, 400, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($fileName, "thumb"), $thumb);
```

The getUploadPath function:

```
public function  getUploadPath($id, $filename, $quality = 'high'){
    return 'public/img/bathroom/'.$id.'/'.$quality.'/'.$filename;
}
```

I want the image to fit in xpx x xpx without scaling or downgrading quality.
The images are  created and stored as expected but the image is not resized. How can I make the image resize?

Comment: Have you tried `$img->save();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stream it (`$thumb->stream();`) before saving by `Storage` facade as below:

```
$thumb = clone   $img;
$thumb->resize(400, 400, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});

$thumb->stream();

Storage::put(  $this->getUploadPath($fileName, "thumb"), $thumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `save($img)` method to actually create the resized image.

This is what the official docs have to say about this -

> To create actually image data from an image object, you can access
> methods like `encode` to create encoded image data or use `save` to write
> an image into the filesystem. It's also possible to send an HTTP
> response with current image data.

```
Image::make('foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200)->save('bar.jpg');
```

Details on the method in the official docs - http://image.intervention.io/api/save

Comment: How does save put it in storage?

Comment: `save()` simply creates new image after you've resized it. You still have to use `Storage::put` to put it in the storage.

Answer (score -1):

```
     if ($request->hasFile('image-file')) {
        $image      = $request->file('image-file');
        $fileName   = 'IMG'.time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->resize(400, 400, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
        });

        $img->stream();

        Storage::disk('local')->put('public/img/bathroom/'.'/'.$fileName, $img, 'public');
     }
```

Hope this works for you!!