# How to save image intervention stream image in public folder laravel

Tags: laravel, image, intervention

I'm saving image file in storage folder, its working fine

```
$ext = "jpg";
$imageConvert = \Image::make($image->getRealPath())->stream($ext, 60);
            $img = rand(10, 100) . '_piku.' . $ext;
            \Storage::put('public/piku/' . $img, $imageConvert);
```

But I want to store images in direct public/piku folder instead of storage/app/public/piku

So how can I do that?

I have tried all these: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62377351/laravel-image-intervention-resize-and-put-in-storage)
But these methods not work for case of intervention stream.

Answer (score 1):

try using [public_path](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-public-path) function:

The `public_path` function returns the fully qualified path to your application's public directory.

```
$imageConvert->save(public_path('piku/' . $img));
```

Comment: It shows this error:
Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::save()